# Could someone explain to me a simple opamp problem, please?

Tags: operational-amplifier

Could anyone please explain to me why a simple voltage follower misbehaves in certain configuration:

Opamp LM358 configured as voltage follower.
Working case:
Vcc 12V.
+IN: pulled up to 5V with 10k resistor.
OUT: steady 5V, perfect!

Problem case:
The same opamp.
Vcc 12V.
+IN: pin pulled up to 5V with 10k resistor AND A DIODE connected in series,
+IN: pin measured voltage - stable 5V.
OUT: Oscillations Vcc to nearly 5V at about 1KHz WHY?

Comment: What’s on your -in?

Comment: LM358 have a class B output and so there’s horrible crossover distortion, that may be the issue.  Perhaps load the output so it’s either sourcing or sinking current all the time.  Otherwise try an LMV358.

Comment: Show the schematics including power rails and decoupling capacitors and any loading circuits.

Comment: This site has a schematic tool. Please use it or other available tools to provide clear circuit diagrams for your questions.

Comment: @Frog -IN hard wired to OUT.

Comment: @ZigFisher One thing you may consider is that the technical minds here read schematics a lot more quickly than text, with better understanding, without misinterpretation. [Comment has been edited by a moderator.]

Comment: I have no idea how to place any pictures on this site, I'm new to it. Imagine three components connected in series +5V supply - a resistor - a diode - and +IN of an opamp configured as voltage follower. [Comment has been edited by a moderator.]

Comment: @ZigFisher what polarity should I imagine for the diode?

Comment: @ZigFisher:  The problem isn't imagining the circuit from the words.  The problem is in being sure that the words really reflect the circuit.  Diagrams are less ambiguous than words. Additionally, it often happens that you find the problem yourself when you stop to draw the diagram.

Comment: Answer may depend howthe diode is connected, which is unclear. Make it clear with a schematic.

Comment: My thanks to user287001. It makes sense, I understand op-amps better. In the meantime I have rebuilt my project to use LM393 voltage comparator, it simplified the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diode can be reversely biased which blocks the base current of the input transistor stage of the opamp. The needed current can be small, probably only tens of nanoamperes, but it must have a conducting way. 10 kOhm resistor is ok, but reveversely biased diode isn't.

[image]

This TI datasheet image shows that the input current flows internally from +Vcc. There must be a conductive way from both inputs to the ground or to the negative supply or to a signal source which has voltage say 2V less than +Vcc.

BTW. Even the voltmeter can be conductive enough to at least stop oscillations. Check the output when there's voltmeter between the input and GND.

Comment: Thank you! It could be the cause of that unexpected behavior. I'll check if pulling +IN to ground with let's say 1M resistor (and the diode still in series) would make any change.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the following:

The internal pnp transistors and the current mirrors are not correctly biased.

The internal circuitry of the LM358 was designed with the idea that the power supply of the chip has an internal resistance close to zero Ohms.

Try to use an 7805 voltge regulator.